# How to remove unwanted sentences from file

Tags: c#, file, filereader, streamreader, streamwriter

I am trying to remove some unwanted sentences (in this case, sentences with less than 6 words) from different local files and save the cleaned texts into another set of files. So I am trying to read each file in a folder one by one and write all the valid sentences into another set of files located in another folder. I am currently using this code:

```
int shortphrasescount = 0;    
var myUniquefilename = string.Format(@"{0}.txt", Guid.NewGuid()); 
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\input\")
                          .Where(p => p.EndsWith(".txt"))
                          .ToArray();
foreach (var file in files)
{

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\output\" + myUniquefilename);
    writer.Flush();

    var list = new List<string>();
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        list.Add(line);
    }
    string[] sentences = list.ToArray();

    foreach (var sentence in sentences)
    {

        int NumberOfWords = sentence.Split(' ').Length;
        if (NumberOfWords < 6)
        {
            shortphrases += 1;
        }
        else
        {          
            writer.WriteLine(sentence);
        }
    }

    writer.Close();
    reader.Close();
}                    

Console.WriteLine("Deleted a total of " + shortphrasescount + " short phrases!");
```

But this way I only manage to save the last processed document instead of having several cleaned text files as output. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a call to "SaveToFile()" or some such somewhere?

Comment: You're using the same file name for each file you process - you never change it.  Also, you don't need to call `ToArray()` - you can use `foreach` on a `List<T>` just like an array.

Comment: Check these two methods: [ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) and [WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx). They might help you to make the code more readable.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon - `writer.Close()` and `reader.Close()` are the saving mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are all right!

Comment: It should be noted that `sentences` isn't really an array of sentences.  It's just an array of lines.  I would guess you need to split the text by periods, unless you know all the data will have one sentence per line and one line per sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only assign myUniqueFileaname once outside the loop. So the same file gets overwritten each time.

Answer (score 4):

When you create your `StreamWriter` object to write the output, you do so with:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\output\" + myUniquefilename);
```

where `myUniquefilename` is a `string` = `string.Format(@"{0}.txt", Guid.NewGuid());`

The problem is you aren't generating a new file name each time. So you're overwriting each file with the last one. You need to generate a new filename each time, perhaps copying the assignment into the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You generate the output filename once, at the start of the program.

Obviously, you need to generate it once for each file - so move the code

```
var myUniquefilename = string.Format(@"{0}.txt", Guid.NewGuid());
```

into the loop.

Comment: Wow, a tie to the second for answering the question. Not seen this before.

Comment: Oh yes! Didn´t saw that! Thanks a lot Nikki, Gary and Ben for the quickest reply ever!

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you are trying to achieve

```
var myUniquefilename = @"C:\OutputDirectory\{0}_NEW.txt";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\InputDirectory\", "*.txt");

foreach (var file in files)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
    var validLines = lines.Where(l => l.Split(' ').Length > 6);
    File.WriteAllLines(string.Format(myUniquefilename, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)), validLines);
}
```

Comment: This solution will still have the same issue as the OP's question - you'll get one file only, because the output filename is never changed.

Comment: @Tim Actually it won't because of the `string.Format`.

Comment: You don't need the `ToArray` as `File.WriteAllLines` has an overload that will take an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @Tim I didn't either at first.

Comment: @juharr yes right, removed `ToArray()`, thanks for pointing out.